# Get the size of the drawn image, not the actual one

Tags: java, graphics, size, awt, resolution

In my game I scale the Graphics2D object with `g2d.scale(scale, scale);` to make the game look the same in all resolutions. The problem with this is that the images won't rotate properly because they are treated like bigger or smaller than what they actually are. I was wondering if there is a way to get the width and height of the drawn image instead of the actual image or if I would have to manually change the width and height variables depending on what resolution the screen has?

Answer (score 0):

**Take a look at following function.**

```
public void picture(File pictureFile) {
    Image theImage = null;

    try {
      theImage = getToolkit().getImage(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());
      getToolkit().prepareImage(theImage, -1, -1, this);

      while ((getToolkit().checkImage(theImage, -1, -1, this) & this.ALLBITS) == 0) {
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    // these lines will return Height and Width of image
    theImage.getWidth(this);
    theImage.getHeight(this);
  }
```